# custom querySelectorAll implemention

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

This was given to me as an interview question -- didn't get the job, but I still want to figure it out.

The objective is to write two `querySelectorAll` functions: one called `qsa1` which works for selectors consisting of a single tag name (e.g. `div` or `span`) and another called `qsa2` which accepts arbitrarily nested tag selectors (such as `p span` or `ol li code`).

I got the first one easily enough, but the second one is a bit trickier.

I suspect that, in order to handle a variable number of selectors, the proper solution might be recursive, but I figured I'd try to get something working that is iterative first. Here's what I've got so far:

```
  qsa2 = function(node, selector) {
    var selectors = selector.split(" ");
    var matches;
    var children;
    var child; 
    var parents = node.getElementsByTagName(selectors[0]);
    if (parents.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
            children = parents[i].getElementsByTagName(selectors[1]);
            if (children.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
                    child = children[i];
                    matches.push(child); // somehow store our result here
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
  }
```

The first problem with my code, aside from the fact that it doesn't work, is that it only handles two selectors (but it should be able to clear the first, second, and fourth cases).

The second problem is that I'm having trouble returning the correct result. I know that, just as in `qsa1`, I should be returning the same result as I'd get by calling the `getElementsByTagName()` function which "returns a live `NodeList` of elements with the given tag name". Creating an array and pushing or appending the `Node`s to it isn't cutting it.

How do I compose the proper return result?

(For context, the full body of code can be found [here](http://codepen.io/aryman/pen/mVzmgb/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it

```
function qsa2(selector) {
    var next = document;
    selector.split(/\s+/g).forEach(function(sel) {
        var arr = [];
        (Array.isArray(next) ? next : [next]).forEach(function(el) {
            arr = arr.concat( [].slice.call(el.getElementsByTagName(sel) ));
        });
        next = arr;
    });
    return next;
}
```

Assume we always start with the document as context, then split the selector on spaces, like you're already doing, and iterate over the tagnames.
On each iteration, just overwrite the outer `next` variable, and run the loop again.
I've used an array and `concat` to store the results in the loop.

This is somewhat similar to the code in the question, but it should be noted that you never create an array, in fact the `matches` variable is `undefined`, and can't be pushed to.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thanks for showing me how to successfully iterate through the DOM subtree and form that return array. I'm still getting the hang of JS, obviously, and your comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors here:

> ```
> if (parents.length > 0) {
>     for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
>         children = parents[i].getElementsByTagName(selectors[1]);
>         if (children.length > 0) { 
>             for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) { // <-----------------------
> ```

Instead of going over the length of the `children`, you go over the length of the `parent`.

As well as the fact that you are reusing iteration variable names! This means the `i` that's mapped to the length of the `parent` is overwritten in the `child` loop!

On a side note, a `for` loop won't iterate over the elements if it's empty anyway, so your checks are redundant.

It should be the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    children = parents[i].getElementsByTagName(selectors[1]);
        for (var k = 0; k < children.length; i++) {
```

---

Instead of using an iterative solution, I would suggest using a recursive solution like the following:

```
var matches = [];
function recursivelySelectChildren(selectors, nodes){
    if (selectors.length != 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
            recursivelySelectChildren(nodes[i].getElementsByTagName(selectors[0]), selectors.slice(1))
        }
    } else {
        matches.push(nodes);
    }
}
function qsa(selector, node){
    node = node || document;
    recursivelySelectChildren(selector.split(" "), [node]);
    return matches;
}
```